# creating xml doc from scratch with ElementTree

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree

I'm getting an error from the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.ElementTree()
root = ET.Element("configuration")
elem = ET.SubElement(root, "appConfig")
elem2 = ET.SubElement(root, "fileGDB")
print ET.tostring(root)
tree.write(sys.stdout)
```

It throws an exception on the following line in the ElementTree.py module:
    iterate = elem.getiterator # cET compatibility
The exception is:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getiterator'

In the code above:

```
print ET.tostring(root)
```

prints out just fine. I don't understand why it's throwing this exception. What am I doing wrong?

Steve

Answer (score 6):

Okay duh,
I needed to make the following line the last after creating nodes:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
```

Maybe someone else will be as numbskull as I was. :-)